# move line which matches pattern to previous line

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with structure

```
12312
desc: bleh...
9938
desc: blah...
desc: bloh...
desc: blih...
desc: bluh...
9912
desc: blah...
```

and i want to move line which matches pattern "desc:" to previous line or delete '\n' in line which goes before every pattern "desc:".

desired output:

```
12312 desc: bleh...
9938 desc: blah... desc: bloh... desc: blih... desc: bluh... 
9912 desc: blah...
```

I've tried

```
awk '!/desc:/{
 printf "%s ",$0
 getline
 printf "%s \n",$0
}
/desc/{print}' file
```

with no result.

actually all the data is the output of `awk -F\" '{print $4 "\t" $6}'` 
maybe i can do something in the first place?

Comment: Can't get it: `desc: blah...` don't match `9912`, but it moves to it. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: i want to move line which matches pattern "desc:" to previous line or delete '\n' in line which goes before every pattern "desc:".

Comment: Using getline is usually the wrong approach, and it certainly is in this case. Don't even think about using getline until you've read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and FULLY understand all the caveats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sed` oneliner

```
sed ':a $!N;s/\ndesc/ desc/;ta P;D'
```

Will output

```
12312 desc: bleh...
9938 desc: blah... desc: bloh... desc: blih... desc: bluh...
9912 desc: blah...
```

Answer (score 13):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/^desc:/&&NR>1{print OFS}{printf "%s ",$0}END{print OFS}' file
12312 desc: bleh...
9938 desc: blah... desc: bloh... desc: blih... desc: bluh...
9912 desc: blah...
```

**Explanation:**

- `!/^desc:/` match lines that don't start with `desc:` not including the first line in the file `NR>1`.
- `{print OFS}` print an output field separator before the matched line. In `awk` the  default `OFS` is `\n`.
- `{printf "%s ",$0}` print every line without a trailing newline.
- `END{print OFS}` after the file has been read add a trailing newline.

Live demo: http://ideone.com/ajH14u

Comment: cant u explain please. i dont ge the same result. actually all the data is the output of `awk -F\" '{print $4 "\t" $6}'`

Comment: @IgorVoltaic I have added a explanation. It doesn't matter where the data came from as long as it's in the format describe in the question this will work. Saying you don't get the same results doesn't help.

Comment: `END{print OFS}` will add a blank to the end of each line, use `END{print ""}` to only print a newline. You're also adding a second blank to the end of every line by using `printf "%s ",$0` instead of `printf " %s",$0` but you'd need to rethink the script logic to address that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat file
12312
desc: bleh...
9938
desc: blah...
desc: bloh...
desc: blih...
desc: bluh...
9912
desc: blah...

$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(/^desc:/?OFS:ors),$0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
12312 desc: bleh...
9938 desc: blah... desc: bloh... desc: blih... desc: bluh...
9912 desc: blah...
```

Comment: @Jaypal - it's the common awk way to deal with joining lines. You either need to print an ORS (or nothing if it's the first line in the input) or an OFS before each line based on if it's the first line in the block or a subsequent line so you just use a ternary expression to capture the condition that distinguishes the first from subsequent lines in a block.

Comment: True, it's just the use of `ternary operator` inside of `printf` is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ /; ! /^desc:/ and print "\n" unless 1 == $.' FILE
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more intuitive with `print "\n" unless 1 == $. || /^desc:/`?

Comment: I assume `! /^desc:/ and print "\n" unless 1 == $.` means `if desc is not found then print a newline unless there's one only field on the line`. That's a pretty nasty statement wrt comprehension as it's got at least a couple of negatives in it. Isn't there a clearer way to write that? I see a suggestion of `print "\n" unless 1 == $. || /^desc:/` in a comment but can't you just write something clear and simple like `if ($. > 1 || /^desc:/) print "\n"` in perl? I don't even know if that's interpreting the original perl intent correctly.

Comment: Well, this demostrates how I got there: I started with `and`, noticed the empty line at the beginning, so added the `unless`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
g/\v^desc/ normal kJ
saveas! output.txt
q!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim infile
```

And it will create an `output.txt` file with content:

```
12312 desc: bleh...
9938 desc: blah...  desc: bloh...  desc: blih...  desc: bluh...
9912 desc: blah...
```

Answer (score 1):

With the "new" GNU option `-z` you can use

```
| sed -z 's/\ndesc:/ desc:/g'
```