# Sed to print to one line only

Tags: sed

When using Sed to change the format of the information with this code

```
sed -e "1,/\[option\]/i user id is:" -e '/^#/d'  -e 's/~//g' /test/data/USER.FIDS
```

The information comes out looking like below.....

```
user id is:
qqq TTK
user id is:
jeff    TTL RODGERS
user id is:
mark    TP4 THOMSON
```

What I need is for the information to come out looking like this below...

```
user id is:  qqq    TTK
user id is:  jeff   TTL RODGERS
user id is:  mark   TP4 THOMSON
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [move line which matches pattern to previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021770/move-line-which-matches-pattern-to-previous-line)

Answer (score 3):

Since sample input wasn't provided, I'm creating my own and focusing only on the part that needs to be changed. Instead of using `i` command, use `s` like shown below:

```sh
# 'i' command will insert content before matching lines
$ seq 5 | sed '/[135]/i user id is: '
user id is: 
1
2
user id is: 
3
4
user id is: 
5

# with 's' command, you can add content to the same line
$ seq 5 | sed '/[135]/ s/^/user id is: /'
user id is: 1
2
user id is: 3
4
user id is: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, you could try following. Since there is no sample data provided so this has been run and tested with your shown samples output of your shown command.

```
your_command | 
awk '
{
  printf("%s",$0~/^user id/?(FNR>1?ORS:"")$0 OFS:$0)
}
END{
  print ""
}
' | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `/test/data/USER.FIDS` only contains names, and you can use

```
sed '/^#/d; s/^/user id is: /;s/~//g' /test/data/USER.FIDS
```