# move short lines to previous line

Tags: awk, sed

I want to move short lines (let say shorter than 60 characters), to the previous line.

There's a similar question : [move line which matches pattern to previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021770/move-line-which-matches-pattern-to-previous-line)

But it doesn't work for my condition of short line.

I can get all the short lines, like this : `awk 'NF<60' FS= file`.

But I'd like to move them to the previous line.

Example below of what I'd like.
Shorter lines represented by "abc" (length < 4).

BEFORE:

```
123456789
abc
123456789
123456789
123456789
abc
abc
123456789
123456789
abc
abc
abc
123456789
123456789
abc
123456789
123456789
```

AFTER:

```
123456789abc
123456789
123456789
123456789abcabc
123456789
123456789abcabcabc
123456789
123456789abc
123456789
123456789
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `awk`. It delays printing until it saw the next line.
Setting `FS=""` works with **gawk 4.2.1** and above and **mawk** 1.3.4 20200120.
Fails with "original" **awk** version 20121220. (Thanks @Ed Morton for the reminder!). Other versions not tested.

```
% awk -F '' 'NR==1{ line=$0; next }
             NF<=60{ prev=$0; printf("%s%s",line,prev); line=""; next }
             NF>60{ print line } { line=$0 }
             END{ print line }' file
1 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw2 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
3 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
4 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw5 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie6 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
7 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
8 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
```

With "original" **awk** using `length()`

```
% oawk 'NR==1{ line=$0; next }
        length($0)<=60{ prev=$0; printf("%s%s",line,prev); line=""; next }
        length($0)>60{ print line } { line=$0 }
        END{ print line }' file  
1 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw2 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
3 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
4 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw5 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie6 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
7 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
8 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
1 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
2 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
3 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
4 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
5 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
6 owenuof wuoef wue fiwuf wiuenf wie
7 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
8 ewf nwje fwkjef wkejf wkej fwkejf wkejfwkjef woief nowienfw
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the reminder! Included a version disclaimer! I'll add a version with length for completeness.

Comment: Thank you Andre  and Ed, it works!  Studying the code now.

Comment: I can't figure out how the code works. I understand that it gets the first 2 lines, and concatenate them if the 2nd is less than x characaters. But how does it move on ?   After it concatenates, what is the next record ?   Is it the new line generated ?  I guess not, since it would print twice.

Comment: @trogne The base idea behind it is to not print on the normal program workflow but instead save the lines. The rest is checking the length of the data and push them into `line` or `prev` based on the given conditions and print after the conditionals are done. `printf` makes sure to concatenate on one line if the condition is met.

Comment: @trogne Yes, printing twice is prevented by setting `line=""` when the condition is met.

Comment: I still don't get why long lines are not printed twice. If it founds a long line, it prints it. Then if there's a short line, why don't it prints the same long line and the short line ?

Comment: @trogne If it finds a long line it prints `line` not `$0`. Line is the last long line it found and wasn't printed before with any short line.

Comment: I get it all. THANKS Andre!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
length($0) < 4 {
    out = out $0
    next
}
{
    if ( out != "" ) {
        print out
    }
    out = $0
}
END {
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
123456789abc
123456789
123456789
123456789abcabc
123456789
123456789abcabcabc
123456789
123456789abc
123456789
123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;/\n.{4}/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the file.

If the second line does not have 4 (you can alter this to 60 for your purposes) or more characters, remove the newline, append the next line and check again.

Otherwise, print/delete the first of the lines and repeat.

N.B. The `N`,`P` and `D` commands are a bit special read about them [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 's/\n([^\n]{1,6}(?=\n))/\1/g' file
```

The `-0` puts `perl` in "slurp" mode, and `-p` tells perl to print each record after processing.  `-e` specifies that the next argument is the program to run.  That program simply does a search and replace, looking for "lines" (runs of non-newlines) that are less than (in this case) 6 characters long.  The positive lookahead (`(?=)`) is needed to handle consecutive short lines.

You can easily parameterize the line length with something like:

```
 perl -s0pe 's/\n([^\n]{1,$len}(?=\n))/\1/g' -- -len=60 input
```